# Unit testing very simple functions

Tags: python, unit-testing

Say I have a simple function of the form:

```
def square(x):
    return x**2
```

If I write a unit test for testing correctness, is it considered bad  practice to do something like:

```
def test_square(self):
        for _ in range(50):
            rand_num = random.uniform(-10,10)
            self.assertAlmostEqual(square(rand_num), rand_num**2, msg= "Failed for input: {}".format(rand_num))
```

Where essentially instead of writing manual cases, I'm in a sense rewriting the function inside the unit test? Why or why won't this be considered good practice.

I'm assuming there are other tests which check for invalid inputs and stuff; I'm asking this for the very specific case of testing correctness of the function.

Comment: [This question might be better suited for the programmers stack exchange.](https://programmers.stackexchange.com/) What makes a unit test too complex and not complex enough is, ironically, not a simple distinction.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I think my question is not about how complex to make unit tests in general, it is about whether verbatim copying the code for a function to test for correctness is ok?

Comment: With that said, my personal criteria for unit tests basically fall into "Testing For Correctness", "Testing the negative", "Testing Underlying system Failure", "Proving Assumptions", "Error Paths", etc. For me each unit test is broken down into a function and an aspect of that function. Too much complexity comes from overlaps.

Comment: Ah, interesting. I personally believe that isn't an effective way to test. Any logic assumptions made in one will be made in the other. I view unit tests as `input`, `expected output`, `output from function`.

Comment: So you're basically testing the interpretor since your asserting x**2 == x**2. It's also non deterministic since you're using a random so in complex methods it can be hard to recreate the error.

Comment: @Dan, the difference is that the x2 on the Left side of that equation is the output from my function (which may or may not be doing x**2), the one on the right is what I want my function to be doing.

Comment: @7VoltCrayon, You're code is `x**2`, you're asserting square(rand_num) == `x**2`, I think you meant to write square(rand_num) == `rand_num**2`. This is simply asserting `x**2` in your test is equal to `x**2` in your code. This can only fail if your interpretor is broken.

Comment: @Dan, Ah yes sorry fixed that

Comment: @AlexLordThorsen when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat When I originally wrote my comment I interpreted the question very broadly. My first pass made it sound close to "How do I unit test."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Random inputs is almost never what you want.  It wouldn't be very helpful if your tests succeeded sometimes but failed on others because of the different random input your tests generated

You only need to test the bare minimum to ensure correct results.  If you have a bug or regression, you add additional tests as necessary.

This would be sufficient

```
def test():
    assert square(3) == 9
```

Notice that the test doesn't depend on any specific implementation details (i.e. it only includes the computed `9` rather than `3**2`).  In general, you want your tests to have the least amount of dependencies and complexity as possible.  Generally, you're trying to test one thing at a time, and fewer dependencies means you're actually testing the thing you want rather than the interaction with some dependency.

If you noticed a bug with negative numbers, then you could add an additional test

```
def test():
    assert square(3) == 9
    assert square(-3) == 9
```

Often, people will either add unit tests after they've already developed the function, or they'll try to create the entire unit test function at once in the very beginning.

The best method is usually to test one feature at a time, and add one feature at a time, and develop the tests and function together.

Comment: Thankyou, I guess my question is less about the random nature of the input and more about doing: assert square(3) == 9 like you mentioned OR something like x=3, assert square(x) = x**2. Where the expression on the right might be slightly more complicated (say involving a couple of multiplies and adds). Do I manually put the expected value of the output on the RHS or can I just rewrite the expectedFunction there, where expectedFunction is a known working implementation

Comment: @7VoltCrayon You generally want your unit tests to have as few dependencies as possible and have the least amount of complexity, since you're usually trying to test one thing, and having fewer variables involved in the test means less sources of possible error.  In your example, I would only include the hard-coded, computed output in the test if possible, I wouldn't try to code an implementation that produces the same results.

Comment: Your comment is actually the kind of answer to the question I was asking, could you add it to your answer?

Comment: I nearly always start with the simplest input, in this case 0 and `assertEqual(square(0), 0)`.  Such corner cases are too often overlooked.  Aside from that, I agree with pre-calculated answers if at all possible.  Note that `9` would likely have been calculated as `3*3`, so there is actually a test of something.

Answer (score 2):

By copying your code verbatim into your tests you aren't actually checking any assumptions. It's a tautology at that point. Breaking your unit test into `test input`, `function output` and `expected output` you're testing your assumption of how the function should work with the actual implementation.

Since

```
assert function(input)  == function(input)
```

is always true you're actually hurting yourself since your test suit will never report regressions even if they are introduced.

Comment: Good point, but what if someone accidentally changes the square function to return x**3. These tests might be useful in that case?  One slight difference is that I am testing function(x)  == ExpectedFunction(x) where ExpectedFunction is the known desired output.

Comment: If you've hard coded your expected results (so for input=2, output=4, 3 == 9, ...) then if you've messed up your code you'll see it break. [That being said it kind of sucks to repeat yourself which is why I use things like py.test parameterize](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=pytest%20parameterize)

Comment: [It's possible to test specific input and output and still produce minimal code in your tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37552629/double-parameterization)

Comment: "What if someone accidentally changes the square function to return x**3" - 1. this is why it's important that functions are named well to demonstrate the intent of the original programmer. 2. I believe that one additional test case is enough if you are worried about this - as per the highest voted answer, you almost never need a large number of generated test cases.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to write tests using `property base testing`. It is a valid way of testing algorithms. `Haskell.quickcheck` is the first implementation.

It addition to generating the random numbers (in your specified property space), it reduces the set to allow easy debugging of a failing test.

You are in luck: Python has a [QuickCheck](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-quickcheck)